# how to create a virtual copy of git repo on a test server

Tags: linux, git, ubuntu

I am fairly new to Git. I have worked locally, but today i need to setup a remote machine with the git. I have no idea how.

Basically my setup is like this.
I have a windows machine which has a vmware player installed, which is used to connect to the dev ubuntu linux machine where out Git repo is situated. I putty to the dev machine and do all the operation related to git with username common to all the developers username : dev

Now there is a new rollup that is created in the dev git repo which is required to be deployed on our ubuntu linux test server. I have my account in test server. username:ash.

What are the steps that should be followed to setup this. I have some time back had a discussion with one of my colleague who had shared about using SSH key. As he is the only contact person who is not available, I have no info how to proceed. I have created the SSH key.

Comment: It's perfectly possible to do a setup with ssh keys (that's how I do it) but The simplest solution now seems to use gitolite, especially if some users aren't really fluent in linux.

Comment: I dont have access to install gitolote on dev machine or test server machine.

Comment: @dystroy can you please share me the steps that you use to do this.

Comment: You don’t need *any* special access rights to use gitolite.

Answer (score 0):

login to the machine as "ash".

```
ash@gitserver:~$
```

create a new directory that will contain the git-repository

```
ash@gitserver:~$ mkdir rollout.git
```

change into the directory

```
ash@gitserver:~$ cd rollout.git
```

initialize the git repository

```
ash@gitserver:~/rollout.git$ git init --bare
```

go back to your dev machine and clone the newly created repository or add it to the "remote"s of an existing git repo. use "ssh://ash@gitserver/~/rollout.git" as the remote-url.

[update for cloning]: make sure that there is not already a "rollout" directory in the directory where you want to clone to. for simplicity, create an empty directory "foo/" and try to clone into that directory. you can then move the cloned repository to wherever you want to.

push changes to the new repository.......done!

the use of ssh-keys will make authentication simpler and/or more secure but is in no ways necessary (or related) to setting up the git repository.

Comment: After this step "initialize the git repository" 'ash@gitserver:~/misk5.git$ git init --bare'                        I get the message like this 
`Initialized empty Git repository in /home/ash/misk5.git/` 
For the step "clone the newly created repository" 
I am issuing command like this 
`git clone ssh://ash@web-test-2.com/~/misk5.git;` 
`fatal: destination path 'misk5' already exists and is not an empty directory.`
`ssh ash@web-test-2.com`
`ash@web-test-2:~$ ls`
`misk5.git`
I tried removing the misk5.git but still the same error.           How to debug this.

Comment: cloning will create a new directory called "misk5" on your local machine; you can specify an alternative name to clone to as an additional argument: `git clone ssh://ash@web-test-2.com/~/misk5.git local_misk5`